# Isapi rewrite filter ends up in a loop

Tags: isapi

I am using ionics isapi rewrite filter to redirect all .asp files to validate.asp file to do session validation. But I end up in a loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

**my .ini file**

```
ReDirectRule ^/XXXX/(.*).asp?(.*)  /YYYY/validate.asp$2&url1=$1&url2=$2 [R]
```

**validate.asp**

```
<% 
'validation step goes here..

Response.Redirect("../XXXX"&Request.QueryString("url1")&".asp"&Request.QueryString("url2"))
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ini.file**

```
ReWriteRule ^/XXXX/(.+).asp(?:\?(.*))?$ /YYYY/validate.asp?$2&url1=$1&url2=$2 [L]
```

**validate.asp**

```
'validation step goes here..

Server.Transfer("../XXXX"&Request.QueryString("url1") & ".asp")
```

The [Server.Transfer](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_transfer.asp) method sends (transfers) all the state information (all application/session variables and all items in the request collections) created in one ASP file to a second ASP file.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer, but the problem with appending query string with redirected=1, if the user book mark the url , lets say /xxxx/index.asp?redirected=1&... It will always bypass the filter:)

Comment: Ahh yeah it is redirecting. You could also kill the redirects and include the proper file within /YYYY/validate.asp using Server.Execute("../XXXX/"&Request.QueryString("url1") & ".asp?redirected=1&" & Request.QueryString("url2") "). That way the user doesn't experience 2 redirects and the URL stays unchanged.

Comment: Thank you again. If you see my comment, after the user logout, if he tries  to access the same page by using bookmarked url, isapi filter will ignore it, since it will have redirected=1. can we do the redirect flag in the http headers or if any one has different answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to a more simplified solution, the key thing being that there shouldn't be any redirecting nor trough IIRF nor trough ASP's Server.Redirect to preserve the original url for bookmarking. Server.Transfers works with local file paths only so IIRF isn't re-triggered over and over.